# Not able to get the Owner and Performer of the Manual activity

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am creating a event handler to get the activitiy instance details for all the activities.

```
EventSystem.Subscribe<ActivityInstance, FinishActivityEventArgs>(NotifyUser, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

In the "NotifiyUser" function, am trying to get the activityinstance details like (Title, FinishMessage, Owner, Performer and etc..)

I am able to get all the details for "Automatic activities" for "Manual activities" i am not able to get the "Owner" and "Performer" values.

```
private void NotifyUser(ActivityInstance activityInstance, FinishActivityEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        _session = activityInstance.Session;
       logdetails("Activity Owner--->" + activityInstance.Owner.Title);
        foreach (var performer in activityInstance.Performers)
        {
           logdetails("Activity Performer--->" + performer.Title);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this _before_ the activity is committed? Try the initiated phase, maybe those properties are not available anymore?

Comment: Sure Nuno, i will check. However i am able to get those properties for the first manual activity (which is assigned to everyone) and all the remaining Automated activities but not for manual activities. any reason behind?

Comment: Wouldn't think so, it's pretty odd. I'll give it a try on my box

Comment: I always get Owner and Performers for automatic and manual activities in my Event System...

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty weird, I can't reproduce it.

In my code I did this (same subscription as you)

```cs
private void LogSomething(ActivityInstance instance, FinishActivityEventArgs args, EventPhases phases)
{
    User owner = instance.Owner;
    File.AppendAllLines("c:\\temp\\info.log", new[]
        {
            string.Format("Activity ID: {0} owned by: {1}({2}", instance.Id, owner.Title, owner.Id)
        });
    List<User> performers = new List<User>(instance.Performers);
    foreach (var performer in performers)
    {
        File.AppendAllLines("c:\\temp\\info.log", new[]
            {
                string.Format("Activity ID: {0} Performer: {1}({2}", instance.Id, performer.Title, performer.Id)
            });
    }
}
```

Apologies for my crude logging.

This is what I get in info.log:

```
Activity ID: tcm:3-923-131104 owned by: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-923-131104 Performer: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-924-131104 owned by: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM(tcm:0-3-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-924-131104 Performer: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM(tcm:0-3-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-925-131104 owned by: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-925-131104 Performer: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-926-131104 owned by: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-926-131104 Performer: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-927-131104 owned by: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM(tcm:0-3-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-927-131104 Performer: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM(tcm:0-3-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-928-131104 owned by: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
Activity ID: tcm:3-928-131104 Performer: T2011GURUV3\Administrator(tcm:0-11-65552
```

So it seems that this might have something to do with your environment? Maybe a defect on a specific version? I am on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 with Hotfix Rollup 1

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I am not able to get the Performer of my last activity in the workflow. and getting the error "The item tcm:56-1723-131104 does not exist" I tried the with Transactioncommited and Processed phases. I can not use even initiated phase, becasue i need to ge the FinishMessage also.

Comment: I don't think I tried it until the end of the workflow process, and can't continue testing now. Can you try before the activity is Finished (EventPhase.Initiated) and check if its available there? maybe it is expected, I'm not sure on this.

Comment: In the "Initiated" phase am able to get the Performer, but I need the Finish message also of the particular activity, am not getting the finish message if i use the Initiated phase.

Comment: It seems to me that it is by design. The last activity instance (and process instance) is archived and became activity history. So you will need to check not activity instance, but activity history. You can change tcmuri item type from activity instance to activity history to read last archived activity.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that makes sense since the Activity Instance does not exist anymore after it's finished (not an instance of an Activity).